# Appending pairs of columns in Google Sheets

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, spreadsheet

I have a table in google sheets with multiple data like this:

| Name 1 | Value 1 | Name 2 | Value 2 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| John | 22 | Alex | 37 |
| Jack | 15 | Jake | 88 |

I need a formula to make it that way:

| Names | Values |
| --- | --- |
| John | 22 |
| Alex | 33 |
| Jack | 15 |
| Jake | 88 |

Note that keeping the order is not necessary, I just need all the data in two columns.

I've tried messing with Arrayformula but couldn't do it.

Any ideas here?

Comment: Do you only 4 columns or more columns in your real case.?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have only 4 columns then could try-

```
={FILTER(A2:B,A2:A<>"");FILTER(C2:D,C2:C<>"")}
```

If you have more columns then you can add those into curly brackets.

Or using `QUERY()` function.

```
=QUERY({A2:B;C2:D},"where Col1 is not null")
```

[image]